# Checkbox checked state of child node

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, treeview

I am using VS 2005 (.NET 2.0) C# working on a Winform with functionality of XML parsing to a TreeView.

I'm planning to enable the checkboxes of the treeview list. Actually, I already enabled them. I found this code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.checked(v=vs.80).aspx) while looking for some properties of TreeView and TreeNode that might be of help. I found TreeNode.Checked Property and TreeView.CheckBoxes Property.

```
public void HighlightCheckedNodes()
{
   int countIndex = 0;
   string selectedNode = "Selected customer nodes are : ";
   foreach (TreeNode myNode in myTreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes)
   {
      // Check whether the tree node is checked.
      if(myNode.Checked)
      {
         // Set the node's backColor.
         myNode.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
         selectedNode += myNode.Text+" ";
         countIndex++;
      }
      else
         myNode.BackColor = Color.White;
   }

   if(countIndex > 0)
      MessageBox.Show(selectedNode);
   else
      MessageBox.Show("No nodes are selected");
}
```

So I tried it on my test project and it only worked on the parent nodes, not on the child nodes. What I want to do and to happen is that I have to also determine the checked state of the childnodes. I'm working on a project that needs selection of single to multiple child nodes and executing an external program once after checked. Is this possible, with the childnodes? Or are there any other alternatives.

Let me know if I'm unclear on anything. Thank you in advance.

Comment: with `foreach (TreeNode myNode in myTreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes)` you only take top level nodes. if you need next level, take also myNode.Nodes on each iteration

Comment: Does this have a limit on the level of nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change your code to following (It seems to me you have just used code from MSDN). Given code provide a sample answer you could adopt.

```
   // Start from Root type node ; Loop them all
   foreach (TreeNode rootNodes in treeView1.Nodes)
   {
       // Sub note set of current  root
       foreach (TreeNode childs in rootNodes.Nodes)
       {
          childs.Text = "Checked";    // Testing for validity : First level of child

          /*
           * Needs to go further down if we have childs of childs
          foreach (TreeNode child_child in childs.Nodes)
          {
              child_child.Text = "Checked";  // Testing for validity : Second level of child
           }
         */ 
       }
  }
```

Explanation :

Given example will change text for following structure (text Checked Applied to childs)

```
  ROOT
     |-> Child
     |-> Child
  ROOT
     |-> Child
     |-> Child
```

If you un-comment the inner most `foreach` you can can apply it to a structure like below ((text Checked Applied to childs))

```
  ROOT
     |-> Child
          |-> Child
          |-> Child
     |-> Child
  ROOT
     |-> Child
     |-> Child
```

In your code you don't progress further down a `TreeNode` and you have forgotten that each `TreeNode` could contains it's own child node collection.

Simply said,

```
    myTreeView.Nodes[0].Nodes // <- This is wrong for what you want
```

Comment: I did use the sample code from MSDN to see how it'll work and maybe I could probably get some idea from it. But I didn't. I figured the code's lacking or just plain different from what I want. Thanks. I'll take note of that, I'll try that.

Comment: @Kurisuchin that's fine.. Learning is hard but once you learn them they become easy :) Try the suggestions and mark the answer as correct if it solved the problem :)

Comment: well this certainly helped me understand so i guess this did solve the problem. I have to dig down further to understand this fully and implement this on my current project.